How can this question be edited to fit psychology.SE?
I have a question that I'd like to ask on psychology.stackexchange.com, but I'm not sure how to narrow it so that it does not quality as subjective.
I am working on a hobby recommendation engine which you can see a WIP at https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/cgi/hobby-dev.cgi. The essential idea is give a standard Big 5 test, compare with posited average scores for various hobbies, and take something of a statistical distance. (Someone who looked through it closely might pick up that I studied math, and also pick up what infosec types call "a bank vault with a screen door in the back:" the posited average scores are my best, educated guesses, but still guesses.)
I have a subquestions:

How sound or unsound is the general concept, assuming for the sake of balance that my educated guesses are reasonably sound?
How can I (or can I get someone else's help to) improve the posited average scores for a hobby? I've tried, for instance a search for how I got into camping turns up numerous resources on how to get into camping once you have decided you want to so, but did not provide any first page results telling someone's story of "Here's how I got into camping, including my motivation".
If you play with it, how much do the top results appear accurate in terms of whether the top activities are more interesting to you?
What would improve it?

Thanks,

To keep it narrow, just stick to your first question. Drop 2-4. Those could become follow-up questions.
Describe your current understanding of Big 5, how you intend to use it in your recommendation engine, and whether or not there is any reason to believe that Big 5 scores would correlate with preferred hobbies.
Your overarching question would be something along the lines of: Do Big 5 scores correlate with personal hobbies?

https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/hobbies-interests-correlated-with-big-5-scores
